# What is your testing workflow for client-side web development on OS X?

Tags: testing, client-side, frontend

What would be a good workflow on OS X for testing client-side code (HTML/JS/CSS) for browser compatibility and other issues across all major browsers?

I do my web development with Textmate (HTML and JavaScript), CSSEdit (CSS), and use Safari's Web Inspector, mainly for checking the JS console. I do have Parallels with Windows XP on it, but haven't tuned it for web development at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We develop on Macs too so what we usually do is testing and debugging in Firefox with the help of the Firebug plugin and the Web Developer toolbar. We then cross-check stuff in Chrome/Safari using Chrome's built-in Inspector in case of any discrepancies.

For testing on Windows we use a dedicated Windows machine that we can access through Remote Desktop which has some Virtual Machines running various versions of Internet Explorer (one VM for each would be nice, but we just use one for IE6, one for IE 7 and use the IE version that's installed on the remote machine as the third option).

A colleague of mine has a setup with VMWare and running IE right off his Macbook in a VirtualMachine.

As far as I can tell debugging in IE 6 is pretty hard, but some of the newer IE versions have a pretty decent Inspector similar to the ones in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Do you test Firefox and Chrome on Windows at all?

Comment: Not really. We've never encountered any issues with Firefox/Chrome across different platforms. I don't say there aren't any, but we've never encountered them.